# New SSD on Raspberry PI

Tags: backup, storage

I am trying to add a new 8TB SSD (connected by SATA to USB Enclosure) to my Raspberry Pi 4, to use it as a Backup of my 8TB media drive from the PC. I would set this up using openmediavault.

I did initialize the new SSD for the NAS on my pc, and then connected it to the NAS.
The enclosure lights up, which shows, that it gets power. But the Raspberry does not recognize the drive at all.
Using `sudo fdisk -l` in putty only shows me the drives I already had installed before.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!
Silverhammer

Comment: You say `it's connected to the NAS` ... so by "NAS" I guess you mean "Raspberry Pi"? And what does "initialize the new SSD for the NAS" mean? What did you need to do on the PC to "initialize" it? Also, what new USB device shows up in `lsusb` after you connect this new drive? And what output at the end of `sudo dmesg` regarding this drive can you see when you connect the drive

Comment: You might want to clarify that the enclosure has its own power supply, because if it doesn't, that's the problem.